# How to insert selected element from multiple selection into an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi everyone i have a problem.

i have a multiple selection and i want to select something and put it into an input through a button i hope i have been clear :

i manage to get the select item with this jquery code :

```
var chosen= $('#droite option:selected').val();
```

droite is an id for the multiple selection

and i want to put it into the input wich has an id : chosen item here is my jquery code:

```
$("#chosenitem").prepend(chosen);
```

and it won't work do you have any idea why .?

Comment: you need to use `$("#chosenitem").val(chosen);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `val()` on the `select` itself, not the `options` it contains:

```
var chosen = $('#droite').val();
```

Similarly, to set the value of the `#chosenitem` input, use `val()` with a parameter:

```
$("#chosenitem").val(chosen);
```

Note that if multiple options are selected in the `#droite` element, the value returned will be a comma delimited string, eg. `foo,bar,baz`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `val()` to set the value of `#chosenitem`

`$("#chosenitem").val(chosen);`